# Reading a Fasta file from Url address

Tags: url, fasta

I'm using Python 3.4.
I wrote some code to read Fasta file **from internet site**, but it didn't work.
http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta
(I can download and read it as text file, but I'm planning to read multiple Fasta files from given site.)

### (1) The first attempt

```
# read FASTA file

def read_fasta(filename_as_string):
    """
    open text file with FASTA format
    read it and convert it into string list
    convert the list to dictionary
    >>> read_fasta('sample.txt')
        {'Rosalind_0000':'GTAT....ATGA', ... }
    """
    f = open(filename_as_string,'r')
    content = [line.strip() for line in f]
    f.close()

    new_content = []
    for line in content:
        if '>Rosalind' in line:
            new_content.append(line.strip('>'))
            new_content.append('')
        else:
            new_content[-1] += line

    dict = {}
    for i in range(len(new_content)-1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            dict[new_content[i]] = new_content[i+1]

    return dict
```

This code can read any Fasta file in my desktop computer, but it failed to read the same Fasta file from internet site.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> html = urlopen("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta")
>>> print (read_fasta(html))
TypeError: invalid file: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02A62EF0>
```

### (2) The second attempt

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> html = urlopen("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta")
>>> lines = [x.strip() for x in html.readlines()]
>>> print (lines)
[b'>sp|B5ZC00|SYG_UREU1 Glycine--tRNA ligase OS=Ureaplasma urealyticum serovar 10 (strain ATCC 33699 / Western) GN=glyQS PE=3 SV=1', b'MKNKFKTQEELVNHLKTVGFVFANSEIYNGLANAWDYGPLGVLLKNNLKNLWWKEFVTKQ', b'KDVVGLDSAIILNPLVWKASGHLDNFSDPLIDCKNCKARYRADKLIESFDENIHIAENSS', b'NEEFAKVLNDYEISCPTCKQFNWTEIRHFNLMFKTYQGVIEDAKNVVYLRPETAQGIFVN', b'FKNVQRSMRLHLPFGIAQIGKSFRNEITPGNFIFRTREFEQMEIEFFLKEESAYDIFDKY', b'LNQIENWLVSACGLSLNNLRKHEHPKEELSHYSKKTIDFEYNFLHGFSELYGIAYRTNYD', b'LSVHMNLSKKDLTYFDEQTKEKYVPHVIEPSVGVERLLYAILTEATFIEKLENDDERILM', b'DLKYDLAPYKIAVMPLVNKLKDKAEEIYGKILDLNISATFDNSGSIGKRYRRQDAIGTIY', b'CLTIDFDSLDDQQDPSFTIRERNSMAQKRIKLSELPLYLNQKAHEDFQRQCQK']
```

I thought that I could modify my code to read online Fasta file as a string list, but soon I realized that it was not easy.

```
>>> print (type(lines[0]))
<class 'bytes'>
```

I can't remove the dirty 'b' character in the head of each element of list.

```
>>> print (lines[0])
b'>sp|B5ZC00|SYG_UREU1 Glycine--tRNA ligase ...
>>> print (lines[0][1:])
b'sp|B5ZC00|SYG_UREU1 Glycine--tRNA ligase ...
```

### (3) Questions

How can I remove the dirty 'b' character?
Is there any better way to read Fasta file from given Url?

With some help, I think I can modify and complete my code. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm late, but I answer if useful

in python 2

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
fasta = response.read()

print fasta
```

in python 3

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta"
response = urlopen(url)
fasta = response.read().decode("utf-8", "ignore")

print(fasta)
```

you get:

```
>sp|B5ZC00|SYG_UREU1 Glycine--tRNA ligase OS=Ureaplasma urealyticum serovar 10 (strain ATCC 33699 / Western) GN=glyQS PE=3 SV=1
MKNKFKTQEELVNHLKTVGFVFANSEIYNGLANAWDYGPLGVLLKNNLKNLWWKEFVTKQ
KDVVGLDSAIILNPLVWKASGHLDNFSDPLIDCKNCKARYRADKLIESFDENIHIAENSS
NEEFAKVLNDYEISCPTCKQFNWTEIRHFNLMFKTYQGVIEDAKNVVYLRPETAQGIFVN
FKNVQRSMRLHLPFGIAQIGKSFRNEITPGNFIFRTREFEQMEIEFFLKEESAYDIFDKY
LNQIENWLVSACGLSLNNLRKHEHPKEELSHYSKKTIDFEYNFLHGFSELYGIAYRTNYD
LSVHMNLSKKDLTYFDEQTKEKYVPHVIEPSVGVERLLYAILTEATFIEKLENDDERILM
DLKYDLAPYKIAVMPLVNKLKDKAEEIYGKILDLNISATFDNSGSIGKRYRRQDAIGTIY
CLTIDFDSLDDQQDPSFTIRERNSMAQKRIKLSELPLYLNQKAHEDFQRQCQK
```

**BONUS**

It is better using biopython (example for python 2)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import urllib2

url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
fasta_iterator = SeqIO.parse(response, "fasta")

for seq in fasta_iterator:
  print seq.format("fasta")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the primary amino acid sequence (wanting to ignore the header), try the following:

```
link = str(sys.argv[1]) #fasta file URL provided as command line argument
FASTA = urllib.urlopen(link).readlines()[1:] # as list without header (">...")
FASTA = "".join(FASTA).replace("\n","") # as a string free of new line markers
print FASTA
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but trying Jose's Biopython answer no longer works in Python 3. Here's an alternative:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
import requests
from io import StringIO

link = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/B5ZC00.fasta"
data = requests.get(link).text

fasta_iterator = SeqIO.parse(StringIO(data), "fasta")

# Pretty print the fasta info
for seq in fasta_iterator:
  print(seq.format("fasta"))
```